# Explain the output of java code containing interfaces

Tags: java, algorithm, math, interface

I had come across a question for which I am not able to find out why its output is coming as

> 7

when I calculate mathematically it can produce output as 7, 8 or any other number So my question is on what basis its coming as 7 only

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    int A = InterfaceB.B * 2;
}

interface InterfaceB
{
    int B = InterfaceC.C + 1;
}

interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceA
{
    int C = A + 1;
}

public class TestInterface implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB, InterfaceC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A + B + C);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: yes I tried but I am not able to understand on what basis its taking those values

Comment: You should *never* see code like this in reality. I don't think it's worth worrying what horrific code like this ends up doing.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right but I often end up seeing such questions in all interviews and this is from my recent interview. So I should use this platform as getting some more knowledge

Comment: @ankit: That's a really poor interview question, in my view. I'd be disappointed in any interviewer who asked such a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously code like this should never actually occur. It's horrendous. I don't think you should spend too much time worrying about why it gives 7, but it's actually not too hard to see why.

The first field value to be evaluated is `InterfaceA.A`, so the VM starts to initialize `InterfaceA`. That requires `InterfaceB.B`, so it starts to initialize `InterfaceB`. That requires `InterfaceC.C`, so it starts to initialize `InterfaceC`.

Now although `InterfaceC.C` refers to `InterfaceA.A`, the VM is already initializing `InterfaceA`, so it just proceeds regardless (as per [section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) of the JLS):

> If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.

So `InterfaceA.A` is still 0 (we're still trying to work out what value it *should* have, and 0 is the default value for `int`), and `InterfaceC.C` gets a value of 1 (0 + 1). Then `InterfaceB.B` gets a value of 2 (1 + 1), and `InterfaceA.A` gets a value of 4 (2 * 2).

Sum all of those field values, and you end up with 7.

If you use a different expression, you'll get a different value because you'll see a different interface being initialized last, although it only depends on the *first* field which you refer to:

```
A + B + C = 7 (A = 4, B = 2, C = 1)
A + C + B = 7 (A = 4, B = 2, C = 1)
B + A + C = 3 (A = 0, B = 2, C = 1)
B + C + A = 3 (A = 0, B = 2, C = 1)
C + A + B = 6 (A = 2, B = 1, C = 3)
C + B + A = 6 (A = 2, B = 1, C = 3)
```

(You have to *replace* the existing line of code of course, as this is about type initialization - if you just add more `System.out.println` lines you'll get the same answer for all the above expressions.)

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println(A + B + C);
```

When you asked for `A` ( `InterfaceB.B * 2;`) , you need `B`

So, `B`  needs to be resolve,

```
 int B = InterfaceC.C + 1;
```

When you asked for `B` ( `InterfaceC.C + 1`) , you need `C`

So, `C`  needs to be resolve,

```
  int C = A + 1;       //  0+1 =1
```

A is not yet resolved and default is `0`

So int `C`  is `1`.

Now , You need `B`.

```
  int B = InterfaceC.C + 1;   // 1+1  =2
```

Now

```
 int A = InterfaceB.B * 2;  // 2*2 =4
```

Finally

**1+2+4 =7**

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code,then execution starts from the `main` method.In main its `System.out.println(A+B+C)` and as you know control goes from `right` to `left`.
Here in this case `C` is executed first(Because it is present at extreme right) meaning `c=A+1` but `A is 0` so `C=1`.

Now `B` is present to left of `C` so `B` will be executed  this means `B=C+1` so `B=2`(because c is already 1)

As `A` is at extreme `left` so Now `A` is executed this means `A=B*2`
So finally its `4+2+1=7`

Similarly if you print `System.out.println(B+C+A);` then you will get 3